Using optional parameter as input to another method with optional parameter
I am using a method that has optional parameters, and I would (possibly) like to pass them to another method that also uses optional parameters. Can this be done?
Example:
public class FClass{
    public void F(string input1, string input2 = "my default string"){
        // Do stuff
    }
}

public class GClass{
    public void G(string input1, string input2 = default){
        // Do stuff, create someVar
        Fclass.F(someVar, input2) //What can we do here? Note that F does not accept null values.
    }
}

In this case I would like to only send input2 to the method F if it has been sent to method G.
There are ways to do nullchecks etc, but that can become tedious if there are many optional parameters that are supposed to be handled like this.
Note that theses methods are in different classes, therefore it is natural that FClass decides the default input for method F instead of passing that responsibility to all other classes that might want to use this class/method.

Either use "" as a default, or make both input2 parameters nullable. string input2 = default is probably generating a compiler warning already, because the default is null. If you want to use the methods the way they are, use null checks. Yes, it's cumbersome but that's how the methods were designed

what exactly do you mean by "send input2 [...] if ..."? When you don't provide a value for input2, it's value is set to the default value and passed to F. You cannot prevent input2 from being set to something. Either set it yourself, or let the runtime provide the default-value. Do you look for a thrd option?

Did you test this out yourself before posting this question?

If you want to keep the default for value2 in G, you'll need to check if (value2 is null) {Fclass.F(someVar);}.
And this dont make sense, as @PanagiotisKanavos said using String.Empty as default can be a solution, even more i you dont want to handle with null values in the FClass

did you try Fclass.F(somevar input ?? "my defaultValue"?

What do you want F(input2) to see if G(input2) is null? Null, my default string, something else? A null is a very specific value, not a missing value. If you want to use it as a missing value, then all methods should accept null as the default. Otherwise you'll have to create your own type that somehow identifies missing values. It's easy to implement in F# and TypeScript using discriminated unions. In C# you'd have to implement this yourself or use libraries like OneOf

BTW in IL the default value is stored in the caller code, not the method. Neither G nor F know what the default is at runtime, they only know they were called using either null or "my default string" by another method.

It all depends on what you want, but an example is:
public class GClass {
    public void G(string input1, string input2 = default) {
        // Do stuff, create someVar

        if (input2 == null) {
            Fclass.F(someVar);
        } else {
            Fclass.F(someVar, input2);
        }
    }
}


This is alright if there is only one default parameter, but what if you have many?
I will at least have two and at that point the code already gets messy.

@Shark32 what do you want to do in the first place? The code becomes messy because a different default is used in each case. If you explain what you actually want instead of how you think it should be implemented, people can help. C# devs are very jealous of functional concepts like string option  or DUs so they've found a lot of ways to emulate them

yes, better to step back than increment the complexity of the code and make it very hard to mantain.

@Shark32, The alternative is to repeat the default value from Fclass. Then you would write Fclass.F(someVar, input2 ?? "my default string"). This will be shorter, but the magical value "my default string" is now written in two places. You could move this magical value to a public const string residing somewhere, and use that const in both places.

@Shark32 an optional parameter tells the compiler what to use when the parameter is missing in the calling code, and does not come into play if the parameter is default or null or anything at all. If you want F to set input2 to "my default string" then you either have to call without the parameter (as in this answer by @JeppeStigNielsen) or add logic into F to check if input2 is null (if nullable) or empty.

Your problem is not possible to solve as stated since G doesn't know whether a parameter is passed or not (i.e. it can't tell the difference between being called without the optional parameter, or being passed the default of null). This is because the default value is baked into the caller at compile time.
But it can be solved if you use method overloading instead:
public class GClass{
    public void G(string input1){
        new FClass().F(input1);
    }
    
    public void G(string input1, string input2){
        new FClass().F(input1, input2);
    }
}

By doing this, it is clear that the first method will use the default parameter (""my default string"") when invoking G, and the second won't.

How would you do this with 2 optional parameters? Use 4 constructors to cover each case?

Basically yes..

That's what Microsoft does in the BCL. Many methods with lots of overloads there...

Avoid passing the default value in the optional parameter declaration and instead manage it manually.
public class FClass{
    public void F(string input1, string input2 = default!){
    input2 ??= "my default string";
        // Do stuff
    }
}

public class GClass{
    public void G(string input1, string input2 = default){
        Fclass.F(someVar, input2)
    }
}

